# Menulibre crashes cinnamon: Keeps starting in fallback mode

Tags: linux, start-menu, cinnamon, configuration-managment

I created a new launcher in menulibre. After saving, menulibre crashed into fallback mode. Restarting my computer does not help. The menus are currupted.

See the error message here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYW0M.png

I found out, that the menus are located under:

```
/home/<USER>/.config/menus
```

I found a hint that it might work to delete the menus folder:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=353581

Is it safe to do that and will it restore my menus?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link:

https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3925

Two suggestions were:

1. Open the menu editor

   ```
   cinnamon-menu-editor
   ```

   This did not work for me.
2. Delete or rename cinnamon-applications.menu (ATTENTION: THIS WILL RESET YOUR MENUS!)

   ```
   cd ~/.config/menus
   rm cinnamon-applications.menu
   ```

   This worked for me.